# Add fee lines in Single Order woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to add this fee line via a function or woo Hook in single order page in admin panel?
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1rfY.png)

Comment: Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions

Comment: To make order editable to add fee lines, the order status need to be in "Pending" or in "On hold". that's all.